# Removing an object from an array by a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, object

I'm writing an endpoint to delete a record from a dummy database. The dummy database right now is written as an array of objects (it will then be changed to a class, then an actual database).

I have a `dbHelpers.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    createId(data) {
    // ...
    },

    findById(data, recordId) {
    // ...
    },

    deleteById(data, recordId) {
        data.splice(data.findIndex(item => item.id === recordId), 1)
        return data;
    }
};
```

And i'm calling it in `controllers/envelope.js`

```
exports.deleteEnvelope = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const envelopes = await dbEnvelopes;
        const envelope = findById(envelopes, id);

        if (!envelope) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: 'Envelope Not Found',
            });
        }

        const updatedEnvelopes = deleteById(envelopes, id);
        return res.status(200).send(updatedEnvelopes);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
};
```

However, for some reason, my  `findIndex` function is not working and it's always returning `-1`. What is wrong with the function?

Below is the dummy db in `config/db.js`:

```js
const envelopes = [
    {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Rent",
            "budget": 1000
    },
    {
            id: 2,
            "title": "Groceries",
            "budget": 300
    },
    {
            id: 3,
            "title": "Entertainment",
            "budget": 400
    }
]

module.exports = envelopes;
```

Comment: May you provide an example of `data`?

Comment: Also `recordId`

Comment: @evolutionxbox, updated with the dummy db.

Comment: Looks like using `==` instead of `===` fixed the problem.

Comment: @user7496931 then your `recordId` is a string, not a number. Hence why I asked for it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use array.filter to remove the object in array by matching the id.

```
deleteById(data, recordId) {
    return data.filter(item => item.id !== recordId)
}
```